# Galera cluster reporting WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use when importing large db

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a Galera cluster of 6 nodes each with an innodb_pool=4G and when importing a db that I've imported before it fails with the `WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use`. The db is very large, around 5G dump file.

Any tips and tricks to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the config on each machine that was setting the `innodb_pool=4G` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1` and this then seemed to work fix the issue. So there is some conflict between these settings and importing a large db, but I'm not sure what it is at the moment. Will update if I figure it out.

Comment: How much RAM on each node?